# Kotlin - How to properly parallel process data?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous

I am scraping a website for information. A fragment holds two methods that retrieve the data and then draws it. I had to asynchronously process the data to prevent the main thread from being locked up. However, when I run my code it is clear that the asynchronous data processing is occurring out of order and this is leading to some index being out of bounds. I am unsure of what to do. I tried to limit the parallelism is one which did not help. What am I missing?

```
 private fun openinsiderGetData(): DataFrame<Any> {
        val doc = Jsoup.connect("http://openinsider.com/search?q=TSLA").get()
        val table = doc.select(".tinytable")
        val dataMap =  HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()


        table.select("thead").select("tr").forEach {row ->
            row.getElementsByTag("th").forEach { cell ->
                dataMap[cell.text()] = ArrayList<String>()
            }
        }
        // Get the table body cells
        val keys = dataMap.keys.toList()
        Log.d("Keys", keys.toString())

        table.select("tbody").select("tr").forEach {row ->
            var index = 0
            for (i in 0..row.getElementsByTag("td").size) {
                val key = keys[index]
                Log.d("Key", key)
                index += 1
                Log.d("CELL TEXT:", row.getElementsByTag("td")[i].text())
                dataMap[key]?.add(row.getElementsByTag("td")[i].text())
                Log.d("DATA SO FAR", dataMap.toString())
            }
        }
        Log.d("Map:", dataMap.toString())

        val df = emptyDataFrame<Any>()
        for (key in dataMap.keys) {
            val column = columnOf(dataMap[key]) named key
            df.add(column)
        }
        Log.d("Dataframe:", df.toString())
 
        // process the data further
        return df
    }

}

  private fun setupData() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default.limitedParallelism(1)) {
                data = openinsiderGetData()
                val rows = data.values(byRows=true)
                Log.d("ROWS:", rows.toString())
            }
// TODO - Refactor Draw the table
```

My log of my data gives:

```
{Insider Name=[D], Filing Date=[2023-08-08 20:01:17], 1w=[2023-08-04], Ticker=[TSLA], Title=[Taneja Vaibhav], Trade Type=[CFO, CAO], ΔOwn=[S - Sale+OE], 1d=[$261.00], Owned=[-4,000], Price=[104,504], Qty=[-4%], 6m=[-$1,044,000], X=[], Value=[], Trade Date=[], 1m=[]}
```

which is clearly out of order. I am stumped as to how this happens and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with processing the data in parallel. As a matter of fact, you don't process anything in parallel here, no matter if you limit the parallelism or not. You launched only a single coroutine, so there is nothing to run in parallel.

As in your previous question, you seem to assume keys in a map use some specific ordering, they have their indexes. They generally don't. After adding data to the map, if we fetch its keys, we'll get them in a random order.

One way to fix the problem is by using the `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`. This is a special implementation of a map, which preserves the insertion order. Even better, use `mutableMapOf<String, List<String>>()` function which is the standard way of creating maps in Kotlin and underneath it uses the `LinkedHashMap`.

More explicit solution would be to create a list of keys while parsing the `thead`. Or we can store `ArrayList` objects both in a map and in a list:

```kotlin
val dataMap =  HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()
val dataList =  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()

// while parsing thead:
val list = ArrayList<String>()
dataMap[cell.text()] = list
dataList += list


// while parsing the data:
dataList[index]?.add(row.getElementsByTag("td")[i].text())
```

Comment: I went ahead and used a LinkedHashMap as that best fit my data structure needs. Thanks. Never knew that about a HashMap!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your `HashMap` , because it doesn't maintain the order of insertion, try using `LinkedHashMap` instead.